# Xamarin Forms Android custom frame renderer makes corners rectangular

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms version 5.0.0.2012 and Visual Studio 16.10.2.
I want to use custom renderer for frame in Xamarin Forms Android application to have custom shadows. When I use normal frame, then corners are rounded, but I am not satisfied with shadows. When I use custom frames, application is rendering frame corners and shadows as rectangular (it looks very bad).

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomFrame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace SimpleApp.Droid.CustomControlRenderers
{
    public class CustomFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        Context context;
        public CustomFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
                var element = e.NewElement as CustomFrame;
                if (element == null) return;

                if (element.HasStrongShadow)
                {
                    Elevation = 50.0f;
                    var strongShadowColor = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ColorExtensions.ToAndroid(element.StrongShadowColor);
                    var lightGrayColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(206, 208, 210);
                    SetOutlineSpotShadowColor(lightGrayColor);
                    SetOutlineAmbientShadowColor(strongShadowColor);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

HasStrongShadow is my custom property.
What should I do to have rounded corners and use custom renderer in the same time?

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to have rounded corners and use custom renderer in
> the same time?

You can define property `CornerRadius` in your CustomFrame.

Please refer to the following code:

1.define a Custom Frame(`CustomFrame`) in forms:

CustomFrame.cs

```
public class CustomFrame: Frame
{
    public new static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomFrame), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(CustomFrame));

    public CustomFrame()
    {
        // MK Clearing default values (e.g. on iOS it's 5)
        base.CornerRadius = 0;
    }

    public new CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }
}
```

2.create  class `CustomFrameRenderer` in android:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using FrameRendererApp;
using FrameRendererApp.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using FrameRenderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FrameRenderer;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomFrame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace FrameRendererApp.Droid
{
    public class CustomFrameRenderer: FrameRenderer
    {
        public CustomFrameRenderer(Context context): base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && Control != null)
            {
                UpdateCornerRadius();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(CustomFrame.CornerRadius) ||
                e.PropertyName == nameof(CustomFrame))
            {
                UpdateCornerRadius();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateCornerRadius()
        {
            if (Control.Background is GradientDrawable backgroundGradient)
            {
                var cornerRadius = (Element as CustomFrame)?.CornerRadius;
                if (!cornerRadius.HasValue)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var topLeftCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.TopLeft);
                var topRightCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.TopRight);
                var bottomLeftCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.BottomLeft);
                var bottomRightCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.BottomRight);

                var cornerRadii = new[]
                {
                    topLeftCorner,
                    topLeftCorner,

                    topRightCorner,
                    topRightCorner,

                    bottomRightCorner,
                    bottomRightCorner,

                    bottomLeftCorner,
                    bottomLeftCorner,
                };

                backgroundGradient.SetCornerRadii(cornerRadii);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3.usage:

```
    <framerendererapp:CustomFrame
          CornerRadius="30,30,30,30"
          HasShadow="True"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
    </framerendererapp:CustomFrame>
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this solution (custom renderer) is working with Xamarin Forms 3.6 and is not cooperating with newest Xamarin Forms 5.0. For me it is a bug in Xamarin Forms library. I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: The version of xamarin form nuget in my demo is 5.0.0.2012,which is also the latest stable version currently.